# Simple workbooks.open code results in 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a file using

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\AGR Data\16-17 EY Trainee test.xls")
```

but I get a run time error 1004 stating file couldn't be found. I know it is there so what am I doing wrong?

If I use

```
sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", 
Title:="Open Workbook")
```

to allow me to chose the file it works but I don't want to do that for this particular macro.

Comment: Are you certain that it is a .xls and not .xlsx? Is there any other code before this? Where is this code?

Comment: Is it already open?

Comment: It is an .xls file ,it isn't open and preceeding code apart from dim statements is only 
'    Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String
    Dim wbThisWB As Workbook
    Dim wbTheOtherWB As Workbook
    Dim vfilename As Variant
    Dim WSName As String
           
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       
   Workbooks.Open ("C:\AGR Data\16-17 EY Trainee test.xls")
           Set wbThisWB = ThisWorkbook
        sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook")

Comment: Can you open the file manually in Excel? Copy the path from your code, change from VBA editor to Excel, call the open dialog and paste the path into the field.

Comment: Or, vice versa, open the file in Excel (click thru the dialog), change to VBA and enter   `? activeworkbook.Fullname` in the immediate window. Then paste the result to your code.